# diff-mode: how to highlight whitespace characters?

Tags: whitespace, newlines, diff-mode

with `emacs -Q`, I can use `M-x whitespace-mode` :

[image]

But in diff-mode, if I use `M-x whitespace-mode` this is what I get:

[image]

you can see the tabs/space/newlines aren't shown (highlighted).

How can I make `diff-mode` show whitespace like first image?

Comment: The question is not clear: whether you want to enable `whitespace-mode` in `diff-mode`, or keep whitespace highlighting from the original buffer, for example, by changing diff colors from background to foreground.

Comment: @link0ff edited. I want to enable `whitespace-mode`

Comment: For clarity, if you use `M-x whitespace-mode` in a diff buffer, that has the desired visual effect?  And you just want to know how to automate that?

Comment: No it does not have desired effect. I edited the question.